# I would like to refresh my listview which is inside modal for react-native

Tags: listview, modal-dialog, react-native

I am using `list view` inside my `modal`.

That list view is indicating items and check box.

When I am checking item from list, I want that user can see the check box to be checked. I want to show check/uncheck action on `list view`, which is inside my modal.

Problem is that its not rendering the list view, which is inside modal, on changing the state.

**Edit code:**

```
<Modal 
  transparent={true} 
  animationType={'fade'} 
  visible={this.state.isModalOpenStop} 
  onRequestClose={() => {}} > 
 <View> 
   <ListView 
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false} 
    dataSource={this.state.tagJson} 
    renderRow={this.renderTag} 
    style={styles.listView} 
    enableEmptySections={true} /> 
 </View> 
</Modal>
```

Comment: Please provide either some code or describe what you've tried already

Comment: Following is my code:   <Modal transparent={true}  animationType={'fade'}    visible={this.state.isModalOpenStop}
      onRequestClose={() => {}}
      >


      <View>

     


      <ListView
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        dataSource={this.state.tagJson}
        renderRow={this.renderTag}
        style={styles.listView}
        enableEmptySections={true}
      />
  </View>  
  </Modal>

Comment: My list view contain item name and check box next to it, now when I click on checkbox, I want to render the list view again to make it visible that user has checked the check box. But my list view is not getting refreshed.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?